# jQuery.Callbacks - Removing anonymous function callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

After adding a callback function to $.Callbacks(), I want to remove it again:

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks(),
    foo = function() { console.log('Hello world') };

callbacks.add(foo);
callbacks.fire(); // logs 'Hello world'
callbacks.remove(foo);
callbacks.fire(); // nothing to trigger, removed perfectly
```

**So, that works**, but now I want to add an anonymous function, like so:

```
callbacks.add(function(){ console.log('Hello anonymous world') });
callbacks.fire(); // logs 'Hello anonymous world'
```

Looks fine, **but I can't remove the function anymore**:

```
callbacks.remove(function(){ console.log('Hello anonymous world') });
callbacks.remove();

callbacks.fire(); // still logs 'Hello anonymous world'
```

**Is there a way to overcome this?**

Comment: Functions are identified by pointer. You have no pointer to your anonymous function, so you have nothing to pass to `remove()` to tell it which function to remove. Simply passing a duplicate function doesn't do it, because the duplicate has a different pointer. You need to stick with assigning the function to a variable, then passing that variable to `remove()`.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to detect the anonymous function and assign a variable to it. Then, when removing another anonymous, check to see if they are the same?

Comment: No. They will never be the same because they have different pointers.

Comment: And there's no way to compare the two functions? Some stringify magic perhaps? (strip whitespace, etc...)

Comment: It's not built-in to `$.Callbacks()`. You'd have to get the source and extend it.

Comment: @Kriem - Why can't you just keep a reference? What are the conditions for removal (e.g. does it get removed after the first firing, on another event, etc.)? Can you remove all callbacks at once or does it have to be just one at a time?

Comment: @JonathanM - Right, sounds good. Perhaps you can make this a real answer?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir - Sometimes I don't want to create a reference. Also, I find it more complete if $.Callbacks() would work the way I describe it. Just a convenience thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per OP Request:

Functions are identified by pointer. You have no pointer to your anonymous function, so you have nothing to pass to remove() to tell it which function to remove. Simply passing a duplicate function doesn't do it, because the duplicate has a different pointer. You need to stick with assigning the function to a variable, then passing that variable to remove().

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/

Answer (score 0):

You could remove it from within the function itself (like at the last line of the function) using arguments.callee (a reference to itself) although arguments.callee is not valid in 'strict mode'.